# How to implement https support for Perl's HTTP::DAV

Tags: perl, https, webdav

I am trying to access a remote server via the WebDav protocol, and more specifically Perl's HTTP::DAV module.

According to its documentation the coupling to a remote directory takes place in the following manner:

```
use HTTP::DAV;
 
$d = HTTP::DAV->new();
$url = "http://host.org:8080/dav/";
 
$d->credentials(
   -user  => "pcollins",
   -pass  => "mypass", 
   -url   => $url,
   -realm => "DAV Realm"
);
 
$d->open( -url => $url )
   or die("Couldn't open $url: " .$d->message . "\n");
```

I created a local webdav directory and can access it flawlessly over the `http protocol`.

According to `HTTP::DAV`'s documentation, there should be and `https` support as well using the `Crypt::SSLeay` module.

The `Crypt::SSLeay`'s documention offers us the following synopsys using inside the `LWP::UserAgent` module, thus providing for us web resource access over the `https` protocol:

```
use Net::SSL;
use LWP::UserAgent;
 
my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 },
);
 
my $response = $ua->get('https://www.example.com/');
print $response->content, "\n";
```

My question is:
How can I combine the `HTTP::DAV and Crypt::SSLeay` modules in order to have web resource access over the `WebDav and https` protocols?

Something like the following:

```
use HTTP::DAV; 

$d = HTTP::DAV->new();

$url = "https://host.org:8080/dav/";

#...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is untested, but from skimming the documentation, this should work:

```
$d->get_user_agent->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 0 );
```

The documentation for [HTTP::DAV](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::DAV) says:

> **get_user_agent**
>
> Returns the clients' working HTTP::DAV::UserAgent object.
>
> You may want to interact with the HTTP::DAV::UserAgent object to modify request headers or provide advanced authentication procedures.

HTTP::DAV::UserAgent isn't documented, but [its source code](https://metacpan.org/source/COSIMO/HTTP-DAV-0.49/lib/HTTP/DAV/Comms.pm#L322) shows it's a subclass of LWP::UserAgent. The documentation for [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) mentions the `ssl_opts` method for setting SSL options for the user agent object.